# Gson same serialize name with retrofit

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit

The backend I work with return's in one Api 'type' as Object and with another Api 'type' as a String, I use Movie and when I parse it with Retrofit (Gson) I get error.
I understand that I need to write an Desiralize but I had no success doing it.

```
public class MovieResponse extends Movie {
    @SerializedName("media") @Expose public **String media**;
  }


public class Movie {
  @SerializedName("media")  **private Media media**;
  @SerializedName("id") @Expose private Integer id;
  @SerializedName("eventTypeId") @Expose private Integer eventTypeId;
  @SerializedName("typeName") @Expose private String typeName;
  @SerializedName("title") @Expose private String title;
  @SerializedName("englishTitle") @Expose private String englishTitle; ...
```

my json response:

```
{
  "query": "ab",
  "events": {
    "movies": [
      {
        "id": 2561599,
        "title": "bla",
        "englishTitle": null,
        "media": "http://images.com/w/a.jpg",
        "typeName": "movie",
        "eventTypeId": 178
      }
    ],
    "tvshows": [
      {
        "id": 1761630,
        "title": "a'",
        "englishTitle": "Ramat Aviv Gimel",
        "media": "http://c.jpg",
        "typeName": "tvshow",
        "eventTypeId": 166
      },
      {
        "id": 2855624,
        "title": "b",
        "englishTitle": "Lost in Africa",
        "media": "http://d.jpg",
        "typeName": "tvshow",
        "eventTypeId": 166
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you need this `@SerializedName("media")  **private Media media**;`? can't you have just a String there?

Comment: No, because in other places I use the Media Object (the source of the problem is the api architecture, but I can't change it).

Comment: then you need to remove `@SerializedName("media") @Expose` in your media class, and register a `Media` deserializer with gson. This tutorial looks about ok for that purpose: http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/